# All the controls are not getting executed in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Part of the page is not getting executed. On my button click I am generating the purchase order and on the same button click I am also generating a PDF for the purchase order.
But for creating that purchase order I am redirecting the controls to another page & after creating the purchase order in pdf format the controls are to come back to the same page, but unfortunately my last line of the code is not getting executed.

This line is not getting executed.
`msg_pnl.Visible = true;`

I don't know why it is happening.
Can anyone tell me the reason for this?

```
string sell_order_number = Request.QueryString["on"].ToString();
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sell_order_number) == false)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Repeater1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            HiddenField product_id = Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("hf_p_id") as HiddenField;
            HiddenField selling_product_id = Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("hf_selling_product_id") as HiddenField;
            HiddenField tax_id = Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("hf_tax_id") as HiddenField;
            string quantity = ((DropDownList)Repeater1.Items[i].FindControl("qty_txt")).SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (quantity != null)
            {
                string str = "update RS_Sell_Order_Mapping set quantity ='" + quantity + "' where product_id = '" + product_id.Value + "' AND sell_order_no = '" + sell_order_number + "'";
                cm.TableInsert(str);
            }

            //Inserting Sells Invoice Info For Storing Old Price                 
            string InsertSellsInvoiceInfo = "insert into RS_Sells_Invoice_Info_Master (sell_order_no,product_id,selling_product_id,qty,tax_id) values('" + sell_order_number + "','" + product_id.Value + "','" + selling_product_id.Value + "','" + quantity + "','" + tax_id.Value + "')";
            cm.TableInsert(InsertSellsInvoiceInfo);
        }
        UpdateSO_as_Created(sell_order_number);

        Uri uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        String host = uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host + ":" + uri.Port;

        string retailer_id = Request.QueryString["rid"].ToString();
        string WarehouseAddress = Request.QueryString["wid"].ToString();
        string retailer_code = Request.QueryString["rcode"].ToString();
        string officeAddress = Request.QueryString["oid"].ToString();
        string url = host + "/pdf-sell-order/Default.aspx/?on=" + sell_order_number + "&rid=" + retailer_id + "&wid=" + WarehouseAddress + "&rcode=" + retailer_code + "&oid=" + officeAddress;
        string urlToConvert = url.Trim();

        // Create the PDF converter.   
        PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();

        // Performs the conversion and get the pdf document bytes that can 
        // be saved to a file or sent as a browser response
        byte[] pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(urlToConvert);

        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-type", "application/pdf");
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", pdfBytes.Length.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment/pdf; filename=" + sell_order_number + ".pdf");

        // send the generated PDF document to client browser
        // get the object representing the HTTP response to browser
        HttpResponse httpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        pdfConverter.SavePdfFromUrlToFile(urlToConvert, Server.MapPath("../doc/Sell-Order/" + sell_order_number + ".pdf"));

        httpResponse.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);

        msg_pnl.Visible = true;
```

Comment: hey Mr. Leppie do you know the reason for this.

Comment: If you think logically, the response in this case is a PDF attachment and not a new HTML page. Once you've sent a file for download you can't also send a new HTML. On another note this code is so dangerous my eyes hurt...

Comment: This msg_pnl is in first page or in second page ?

Comment: it is in the first page

Comment: Mr Cyberdude, why this code is dangerous what is the wrong in this code

Comment: Are these codes living inside of a try catch block?

Comment: yes they are already inside the try catch block & what is the connection of try catch block with my issue